# What is the Data Type for Datetime and Enum in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert my data into MySQL Database using Prepared Statements. I have several different data types and hence I am using `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` for it to work. However, my data types include decimals, enum and datetime. May I know what should I put in their data types as?

This is my code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO booking (bikeid,type,price,starttime,duration,quantity,totalprice,status,uname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        
$queryStatement= mysqli_prepare($connection,$query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($queryStatement, ' ',$bikeid,$type,$price,$starttime,$duration,$quantity,$);
```

Comment: For `totalprice` you can use `float` data type, for `status` which I assume is enum you can pass one of the value of emum in `string` data type, and for `uname` you can use `string` data type. For `datetime` use the `Date()` method of PHP which returns datetime format compatible with MySQL timpestamp.

Comment: Consider switching to PDO.